# How to type-hint a method that retrieves dynamic enum value?

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a Python module that has a number of simple enums that are defined as follows:

```
class WordType(Enum):
    ADJ = "Adjective"
    ADV = "Adverb"

class Number(Enum):
    S = "Singular"
    P = "Plural"
```

Because there are a lot of these enums and I only decide at runtime which enums to query for any given input, I wanted a function that can retrieve the value given the enum-type and the enum-value as strings. I succeeded in doing that as follows:

```
names = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)

def get_enum_type(name: str):
    enum_class = [x[1] for x in names if x[0] == name]
    return enum_class[0]

def get_enum_value(object_name: str, value_name: str):
    return get_enum_type(object_name)[value_name]
```

This works well, but now I'm adding type hinting and I'm struggling with how to define the return types for these methods: I've tried `slice` and `Literal[]`, both suggested by `mypy`, but neither checks out (maybe because I don't understand what type parameter I can give to `Literal[]`).

I am willing to modify the enum definitions, but I'd prefer to keep the dynamic querying as-is. Worst case scenario, I can do `# type: ignore` or just return `-> Any`, but I hope there's something better.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have MyPy (which is intrinsically a static type checker) automatically infer the results of such a dynamic lookup without a lot of hand-holding. Amd by "a lot of hand holding" I mean a massive great stack of overloads listing each and every name -> result pair.

Comment: I am not sure your *initial* problem solution is even optimal. Even if `object_name` and `value_name` are derived dynamically, a simple `getattr` would do. Either way, for typing to be meaningful you need a listing/mapping of Enums and could just as well refactor this dynamic code while you are at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't want to check-type for *any* `Enum`, I suggest to introduce a base type (say `GrammaticalEnum`) to mark all your `Enum`s and to group them in an own module:

```
# module grammar_enums
import sys
import inspect
from enum import Enum


class GrammaticalEnum(Enum):
    """use as a base to mark all grammatical enums"""
    pass


class WordType(GrammaticalEnum):
    ADJ = "Adjective"
    ADV = "Adverb"


class Number(GrammaticalEnum):
    S = "Singular"
    P = "Plural"


# keep this statement at the end, as all enums must be known first
grammatical_enums = dict(
    m for m in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)
    if issubclass(m[1], GrammaticalEnum))

# you might prefer the shorter alternative:
# grammatical_enums = {k: v for (k, v) in globals().items()
#                      if inspect.isclass(v) and issubclass(v, GrammaticalEnum)}
```

Regarding typing, yakir0 already suggested the right types,
but with the common base you can narrow them.

If you like, you even could get rid of your functions at all:

```
from grammar_enums import grammatical_enums as g_enums
from grammar_enums import GrammaticalEnum

# just use g_enums instead of get_enum_value like this
WordType_ADJ: GrammaticalEnum = g_enums['WordType']['ADJ']

# ...or use your old functions:

# as your grammatical enums are collected in a dict now,
# you don't need this function any more:
def get_enum_type(name: str) -> Type[GrammaticalEnum]:
    return g_enums[name]


def get_enum_value(enum_name: str, value_name: str) -> GrammaticalEnum:
    # return get_enum_type(enum_name)[value_name]
    return g_enums[enum_name][value_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always run your functions and print the result of the function to get a sense of what it should be. Note that you can use `Enum` in type hinting like any other class.

For example:

```py
>>> result = get_enum_type('WordType')
... print(result)
... print(type(result))
<enum 'WordType'>
<class 'enum.EnumMeta'>
```

So you can actually use

```py
get_enum_type(name: str) -> EnumMeta
```

But you can make it prettier by using `Type` from `typing` since `EnumMeta` is the type of a general Enum.

```py
get_enum_type(name: str) -> Type[Enum]
```

For a similar process with `get_enum_value` you get

```py
>>> type(get_enum_value('WordType', 'ADJ'))
<enum 'WordType'>
```

Obviously you won't always return the type `WordType` so you can use `Enum` to generalize the return type.

To sum it all up:

```py
get_enum_type(name: str) -> Type[Enum]
get_enum_value(object_name: str, value_name: str) -> Enum
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I don't think it's possible to have your dynamic code and have MyPy predict the outputs. For example, I don't think it would be possible to have MyPy know that  `get_enum_type("WordType")` should be a `WordType` whereas `get_enum_type("Number")` should be a `Number`.

As others have said, you could clarify that they'll be Enums. You could add a base type, and say that they'll specifically be one of the base types. Part of the problem is that, although you could promise it, MyPy wouldn't be able to confirm. It can't know that `inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)` will just have `Enums` or `GrammaticalEnum`s in `[1]`.

If you're willing to change the implementation of your lookup, then I'd suggest you could make profitable use of `__init_subclass__`. Something like

```
GRAMMATICAL_ENUM_LOOKUP: "Mapping[str, GrammaticalEnum]" = {}
class GrammaticalEnum(Enum):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        GRAMMATICAL_ENUM_LOOKUP[cls.__name__] = cls
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

 def get_enum_type(name: str) -> Type[GrammaticalEnum]:
     return GRAMMATICAL_ENUM_LOOKUP[name]
```

This at least has the advantage that the MyPy can see what's going on, and should be broadly happy with it. It knows that everything will in fact be a valid `GrammaticalEnum` because that's all that `GRAMMATICAL_ENUM_LOOKUP` gets populated with.